# Cannot resolve RouterLink tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Vanilla Vue CLI installation aside from a handful of pre-installed stuff via NPM.

I've read the online docs, I've read the forums but cannot get the Vue router to work.

I've tried a number of different ways of importing the vue router, but the official document has `import VueRouter from 'vue-router'` and `Vue.use(VueRouter)`.

adding router object results in "Uncaught ReferenceError: router is not defined"

```js
// main.js

import 'bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
//import axios from 'axios'
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { faUserSecret } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)

library.add(faUserSecret)

Vue.use(VueRouter)

export default new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: () => import('./views/Home.vue') },
    // { path: '/login', component: Login },
    // { path: '/about', component: About }
  ]
})

new Vue({
    render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

```
// App.vue

<template>
  <div id="app">

    <div id="nav">
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/groups">Events Near Me</router-link>
    </div>

    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

#nav {
  padding: 30px;
}

#nav a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

#nav a.router-link-exact-active {
  color: #42b983;
}

</style>
```

Results in:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined"

found in

---> <RouterLink>
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
warn @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619
logError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1884
globalHandleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1879
handleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1839
Vue._render @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3544
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118
createComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5972
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5919
createChildren @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6047
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5948
createChildren @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6047
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5948
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6471
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3939
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118
createComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5972
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5919
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6510
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3939
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
(anonymous) @ main.js?56d7:36
./src/main.js @ app.js:2354
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:767
fn @ app.js:130
1 @ app.js:2368
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:767
(anonymous) @ app.js:902
(anonymous) @ app.js:905
Show 12 more frames
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
    at Proxy.render (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1026)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3542)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473)
    at new Watcher (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462)
    at mountComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067)
    at VueComponent.Vue.$mount (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409)
    at init (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118)
    at createComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5972)
    at createElm (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5919)
logError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888
globalHandleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1879
handleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1839
Vue._render @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3544
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118
createComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5972
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5919
createChildren @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6047
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5948
createChildren @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6047
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5948
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6471
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3939
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118
createComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5972
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5919
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6510
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3939
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
(anonymous) @ main.js?56d7:36
./src/main.js @ app.js:2354
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:767
fn @ app.js:130
1 @ app.js:2368
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:767
(anonymous) @ app.js:902
(anonymous) @ app.js:905
Show 11 more frames
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined"

found in

---> <RouterLink>
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
warn @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619
logError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1884
globalHandleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1879
handleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1839
Vue._render @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3544
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118
createComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5972
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5919
createChildren @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6047
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5948
createChildren @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6047
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5948
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6471
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3939
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118
createComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5972
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5919
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6510
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3939
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
(anonymous) @ main.js?56d7:36
./src/main.js @ app.js:2354
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:767
fn @ app.js:130
1 @ app.js:2368
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:767
(anonymous) @ app.js:902
(anonymous) @ app.js:905
Show 12 more frames
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
    at Proxy.render (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1026)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3542)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473)
    at new Watcher (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462)
    at mountComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067)
    at VueComponent.Vue.$mount (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409)
    at init (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118)
    at createComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5972)
    at createElm (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5919)
logError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888
globalHandleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1879
handleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1839
Vue._render @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3544
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118
createComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5972
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5919
createChildren @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6047
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5948
createChildren @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6047
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5948
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6471
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3939
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118
createComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5972
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5919
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6510
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3939
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
(anonymous) @ main.js?56d7:36
./src/main.js @ app.js:2354
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:767
fn @ app.js:130
1 @ app.js:2368
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:767
(anonymous) @ app.js:902
(anonymous) @ app.js:905
Show 11 more frames
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined"

found in

---> <RouterLink>
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
warn @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619
logError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1884
globalHandleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1879
handleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1839
Vue._render @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3544
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118
createComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5972
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5919
createChildren @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6047
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5948
createChildren @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6047
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5948
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6471
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3939
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118
createComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5972
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5919
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6510
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3939
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
(anonymous) @ main.js?56d7:36
./src/main.js @ app.js:2354
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:767
fn @ app.js:130
1 @ app.js:2368
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:767
(anonymous) @ app.js:902
(anonymous) @ app.js:905
Show 12 more frames
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
    at Proxy.render (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1026)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3542)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473)
    at new Watcher (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462)
    at mountComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067)
    at VueComponent.Vue.$mount (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409)
    at init (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118)
    at createComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5972)
    at createElm (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5919)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just provide `router` object to `new Vue({})`.

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: () => import('./views/Home.vue') },
    // { path: '/login', component: Login },
    // { path: '/about', component: About }
  ]
})

new Vue({
    router,
    render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: adding router object results in "Uncaught ReferenceError: router is not defined"

Comment: @stoneferry, did you instantiated `router` object? Like i have shown in the answer?